# How to trigger a function or call a function within the special receive function, after a contract receive ether, in Solidity contract?

Tags: solidity

I want to build a smart contract with the following functionalities. When someone sends ether to my smart contract, the special receive function is invoked (automatically), and within the function the contract sends the amount of ether to a predefined account, and modify a global state.
My contract returns errors when I sent ether. However, when I move the modification of the global states to another function, and invoke it manually after receiving ether, both functions worked, i.e. the receiving account received ether, and the global state was updated.
From the official document of solidity, https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html?highlight=modifier#receive-ether-function, it seems the receive function cannot handle too much operations.

My workaround is to have a cronjob to regularly check for the change in the balance of the receiving (predefined) account, and invoke the function to update the global state. What other solutions I could use in the situation?

Update:
To test if my code works, I call `web3.eth.sendTransaction` from `truffle console`.
The code that throws error,

```
receive() external payable {
     address buyer = msg.sender;
     uint amount = msg.value;
     uint purchasedToken = 10;
     transfer(msg.sender, purchasedToken);
     emit Transfer(theContract, msg.sender, purchasedToken);        
     teamWallet.transfer(amount);
    }
```

The code that works, but require a manually call buyToken,

```
function buyToken(address buyer) public {
    uint purchasedToken = 10;
    transfer(buyer, purchasedToken);
    emit Transfer(theContract, buyer, purchasedToken);
}

receive() external payable {
    uint amount = msg.value;     
    teamWallet.transfer(amount);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the receive code? Is the final recipient another contract? The limit of 2300 gas stipend is enforced by the sender if `transfer()` or `send()` are used.

Comment: Hello. I included the code and how I tested. Do you have any idea what call if I make a transaction through a wallet like metamask?

Comment: Did you try using more gas for `web3.eth.sendTransaction`?